# Como llamar a una función incrementando el tamaño de un vector

Tags: c++, array, funciones, booleano, vectores

Estoy haciendo un juego en C++ (con vectores dinámicos) para la gente con Alzheimer, en la que se generan 2 números aleatorios del 0 al 9 que desaparecen después de unos segundos, si la persona ingresa los mismos dos números que se le mostraron, se van a generar 3 números aleatorios nuevamente y así sucesivamente hasta que llegue a 10.

([Ejemplo de juego](http://labpsi.mdp.edu.ar/WebFormTest/DigitosDirectosInversosTest.aspx?ID=1&tt=1)) Lo empecé hace unos días, me parece que la parte de verificar si los números son iguales a los aleatorios ya está bien, el problema es como llamar a la función `pedirNumeros` y que `n` incremente. Imagino que el problema esta entre el el `main` y la función (cabe aclarar: si o si lo tengo que hacer con la librería `<vector>`, gracias).

```
vector<int> generarVector(vector<int> random, int n);
void pedirNumeros(vector<int> nums, int n);
bool noRepetir(vector<int> VecNums, vector<int> random);

int main() {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Spanish");
    vector<int> random, numeros;
    int  n = 2, i, num;
    random = generarVector(random, n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout<<"Número: ";
        cin>>num;
        numeros.push_back(num);
    } if(noRepetir(numeros, random) == true) {
        cout<<"Bien";
        n++;
        generarVector(random, n);
        mostrarVector(random);
        pedirNumeros(numeros, n);
    } else {
        cout<<"Mal";
    }
    
    return 0;
}

//Función para generar números aleatorios que no se repitan
vector<int> generarVector(vector<int> random, int n) {
    int i, j, c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c = rand() % 10;
        random.push_back(c);
    } for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(random[j] == random[j+1]) {
            random.pop_back();
            c = rand() % 10;
            random.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    return random;
}

//Función de tipo booleana para verificar si los números 
//que ingresó el usuario son los mismos a los números aleatorios.
bool noRepetir(vector<int> VecNums, vector<int> random) {
    bool flag = false;
    if(VecNums == random) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}

//Función que ingresa los números, y después se guarda en un vector
void pedirNumeros(vector<int> nums, int n) {
    int i, num;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout<<"Número: ";
        cin>>num;
        nums.push_back(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te falta agregar n como paráemtro de la función `noRepetir`. Así: `if(noRepetir(numeros, random,n) == true) {`

Comment: ¿Y para que necesito pasar el valor de `n`? Si en el bool solo tengo que comparar que  los números aleatorios sean iguales a los que ingresó el usuario, y ni si quiera tengo que recorrer los vectores con un `for`, ya que si hago eso me da error porque solo comprobaba que fuera igual el ultimo elemento del vector, y no todos.

Comment: Ten cuidado en la función "generarVector" pq imaginate que tienes el vector [2, 3, 4, 5] y por un casual te genera el num aleatorio 5. Llegará a la ultima pos del vector y te mirará la siguienta al último que es NULL. Te podría saltar un nullpoint para arreglar ese caso pon justo enciima de la linea "if(random[j] == random[j+1])" lo siguiente: if(ramdom[j+1] != null)

Comment: @MaxiV Lo necesitas porque en la definición especificaste ese tercer parámetro. Es decir, la función a como la hiciste pide *3* parámetros.

Comment: @FranAcuna Disculpa se me olvido sacarle la `n` antes de publicar el código, lo usé en esa función para probar algo pero ya esta en desuso, de todas formas, sigo intentando desde hace como 2 días y no encuentro solución al problema principal.

Comment: @Carlos Windows gracias, me decia que cambie `NULL` por `0` porque me saltaba una advertencia, me parece que funciona de igual manera.

Comment: Oh ya veo, puedes por favor actualizar tu pregunta con el nuevo código?

Comment: Ahí lo cambie @FranAcuna

Answer (score 2):

Creo que podrías hacer esto de una mejor manera. Pero voy a concentrarme en lo que el problema que vienes a preguntar acá. Según tu pregunta `n` no incrementa correctamente, sin embargo estás teniendo problemas porque generas un vector que no usas para las siguientes iteraciones. Es decir, `n` si incrementa, pero tu vector permanece del mismo tamaño siempre.

Problemas:

1. Cuando generas tu vector no lo estás guardando en tu variable `random`, por lo tanto, tu vector `random` nunca cambia de valor.
2. Aunque arregles eso tu función `generarVector` tiene un problema y es que agrega `n` cantidad de números en vez de crear un nuevo array que tenga este largo, como en el ejemplo que compartiste.

Te sugiero:

1. Haz `random = generarVector(random, n);` para guardar el vector... O mejor aún, pasa el vector por referencia y no por valor.
2. Vacía el vector antes de generar uno nuevo en la función `generarVector` utilizando el método `clear()`.

Siguiendo estás sugerencias podrías tener un código que se vea así:

```
void generarVector (vector < int > &random, int n);
void pedirNumeros (vector < int >nums, int n);
bool noRepetir (vector < int >VecNums, vector < int >random);

int main ()
{
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "Spanish");
  vector < int >random, numeros;
  int n = 2, i, num;
  generarVector (random, n);

  for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
      cout << "Numero: "<<endl;
      cin >> num;
      numeros.push_back (num);
    }
    
  if (noRepetir (numeros, random) == true)
    {
      cout << "Bien"<<endl;
      n++;
      generarVector (random, n);
      mostrarVector (random);
      pedirNumeros (numeros, n);
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "Mal"<<endl;
    }

  return 0;
}

//Función para generar números aleatorios que no se repitan

void generarVector (vector < int > &random, int n)
{
  random.clear();//limpiamos el vector para que se genere un vector de n elementos y no un vector de +n elementos
  int i, j, c;
  srand (time (NULL));
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      c = rand () % 10;
      random.push_back (c);
    }
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      if (random[j] == random[j + 1])
    {
      random.pop_back ();
      c = rand () % 10;
      random.push_back (c);
    }
    }
}

//Función de tipo booleana para verificar si los números 
//que ingresó el usuario son los mismos a los números aleatorios.
bool noRepetir (vector < int >VecNums, vector < int >random)
{
  bool flag = false;
  if (VecNums == random)
    {
      flag = true;
    }
  return flag;
}

//Función que ingresa los números, y después se guarda en un vector
void pedirNumeros (vector < int >nums, int n)
{
  int i, num;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << "Numero: ";
      cin >> num;
      nums.push_back (num);
    }
}
```

Comment: me voy ya mismo a probarlo, muchísimas gracias, se que me faltan cosas todavía por aprender en cuanto a lógica, menos mal que hay gente como vos.

Answer (score 1):

Esta función no tiene sentido alguno:

```
//Función para generar números aleatorios que no se repitan
vector<int> generarVector(vector<int> random, int n) {
    int i, j, c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c = rand() % 10;
        random.push_back(c);
    } for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(random[j] == random[j+1]) {
            random.pop_back();
            c = rand() % 10;
            random.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    return random;
}
```

Por un lado recibes un `std::vector<int>` por copia como parámetro y por otro devuelves dicho `std::vector<int>` por copia. Dedcide qué qué quieres hacer:

1. Rellenar el `std::vector<int>` recibido como parámetro con valores aleatorios.
2. Devolver un `std::vector<int>` rellenado con valores aleatorios.

Uno u otro, no ambos.

Por otro lado, tu algoritmo de generación de números no repetidos está mal, empiezas llenando el `std::vector<int>` con `n` valores:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    c = rand() % 10;
    random.push_back(c);
}
```

Pero después sólo sacas valores **del final** cuando una posición concreta corresponde con la siguiente:

```
for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    // Sólo compruebas si están repetidos números consecutivos.
    if(random[j] == random[j+1]) {
//                         ^^^ <--- Error, j+1 podría estar fuera del vector.
        random.pop_back();
//             ^^^^^^^^ <-- Sacas números del final, pero estás comprobando la posición j
        c = rand() % 10;
        random.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

Eso está mal por varios motivos:

- Pueden haber repeticiones no consecutivas.
- Puedes estar mirando valores fuera del `std::vector<int>`.
- Eliminas valores que podrían no estar repetidos.

Si lo que necesitas son números aleatorios del uno al diez sin repeticiones, lo más fácil es generar una colección de valores sin repeticiones y sacar números de dicha colección, por ejemplo así:

```
std::vector<int> generarVector(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> result{};

    // Valores sin repeticiones
    std::vector<int> valores{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    // Repetimos el bucle 'n' veces o hasta que nos quedemos sin valores.
    for (int i = 0; (i != n) && valores.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Escogemos una posición al azar entre las disponibles.
        const auto posicion = std::rand() % valores.size();
        // Sacamos el valor de dicha posición y lo guardamos en el vector resultado.
        result.push_back(valores[posicion]);
        // Quitamos el valor de dicha posición.
        valores.erase(valores.begin() + posicion);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBdU4MwEHwmv@IcRwpDZFq1fgDlZ/jidJw0RMxIEyYJfZDpb8cjFHWqb5fL7t7u8ra95g1T9TBcSsWbrhJQSG2dEWxfkp/dQXCnTUmIdVWWTa9CKldCLZQwzDz7VYQrUDHpSfAHaITtGtcfc/LP54E1GgH9isINhVsKdxTWFO4pPFB4pPBEYbX01DdtwJ@RsIFljjNcbPAmhOGsklr5KaI4hySRMQnQTMC1sg5Y5zS02koutUK6t2GYqqIYrs7ZyJosp21n3193jH9EJ8jLrLH1sJmIPVgxY9KdqKVC4eT74gg@YgQjXGfUqZCc4GrMs2cjfKzOR/zlOPSSkJ11vY4x3FQl152DopgijMMCFig8DF8)</kbd>.

Comment: Justamente estaba viendo eso, me di cuenta de que no servía y lo cambie, gracias.